# how to overwrite object property value javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have function that is below

```
success: function (file, data) {

   file.name=data;
   console.log(data);
   console.log(file.name);
   console.log(file);

}
```

"file" is object and "data" is simple string. I am trying to overwrite file name for example file.name have value "test" and data have value "umar". Now, in first line I am assigning data value to file `file.name=data;`  but when i print again file.name, I am again geting value "test". That means the value is not being overwritten. Why ?

Comment: Is `file` the name of the object declared outside of your function scope?

Comment: Could you provide more code, please? It's better to see working example. You can use jsfiddle.com or jsbin.com

Comment: we need more context

Answer (score 0):

All else being equal, that will work fine:

```js
var x = {
  success: function(file, data) {
    file.name = data;
    console.log(data);
    console.log(file.name);
    console.log(file);
  }
}

x.success({
  name: "Hello"
}, "World");
```

… if it doesn't then the `name` property will be read only, and there isn't much you can do about that short of using a different kind of object.

Comment: In that case, he could perhaps make a deep copy of the object, with no read-only.